# Three.js shadow not showing

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm struggling with the shadow right now, tried everything for hours but it's still not showing up. What did I do wrong?

This is my current code for the scene:

```
//camera
  const fov = 120
  const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
  const near = 0.1
  const far = 1000
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far)
  camera.position.set(0, 1, 2)
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

  //renderer
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    alpha: true,
    antialias: true,
  })
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
  renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap

  //light
  const light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1)
  light.position.set(-2, 1.8, 1)
  light.castShadow = true
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 512
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 512
  scene.add(light)

  //add sphere
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 16)
  const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
  })

  const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial)
  sphere.position.set(0, 0.2, 0)
  sphere.castShadow = true
  scene.add(sphere)

  //add plane object: ground
  const plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 1, 1)
  const planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xeeeeee,
  })

  const planeObj = new THREE.Mesh(plane, planeMaterial)
  planeObj.position.y = -1
  planeObj.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI
  plane.receiveShadow = true
  scene.add(planeObj)
```

Please correct me if I'm wrong. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. It should be:

```js
planeObj.receiveShadow = true
```

Here is a live example with your fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/w78m4gvr/

Comment: Oh gosh, thank you so much! How can I not see the typo there…. now I really want to kill myself :(